# Combobox Value to match with Query record value

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

How can a combobox value match with a column value in a query.
Provided the combobox record source is from a table

I tried this code but it doesnt seem to work any help is appreciated

```
Private Sub open_button()
  If Me.CboName.Value = "Query!Query_test!Column(0)" then 

    Docmd.OpenForm FormName:="Customer"
  End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to search in all records in this query?

Comment: @gizimo Just the records in the first column of the query

Answer (score 1):

You would need to loop through the query and check each record against the combobox value:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Query_test", dbOpenSnapshot) 'Open Query as Snapshot

rs.MoveFirst

Do Until rs.EOF 'loop through the query

    If rs.Fields(0).Value = Me.CboName.Value Then 'if column 0 matches Combobox

        'do something and exit loop
        DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="Customer"
        Exit Do
    End If

    rs.MoveNext 'next record
Loop

'cleanup
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: @gizimo Thank for the reply but i am not sure if Access will Take rs.MoveFirst , i did try your method and got with a compile error: method or data member not found for rs.MoveFirst.

Comment: @AdityaIyer that's weird, for me it compiles fine. Maybe check if you have set a reference to "Microsoft Office XX.X Access database engine Object Library"

Comment: @gizmo after referencing the error just vanished , now i have a Runtime error'3601': too few parameter Expected 2.

Comment: @AdityaIyer in which line does it occur?

Comment: @gizimo : Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Query_test", dbOpenSnapshot) this one gets highlighted

Comment: @AdityaIyer check if the string matches your query name, other than that, I can't see anything that could go wrong

Comment: @gizmo : The code works when i put the Query, which is the recordsource for the datasheet in the form. but if the recordsource of combobox is different as that of the Datasheet in the form then it gives me Runtime error , what could be done in this case?

Comment: @AdityaIyer could you explain that a little further? I'm not quite sure what you are talking about

Comment: @gizimo: sorry i guess it was a bit confusing. Lemme put it this way , I have a Split form with datasheet at bottom and the record source for that form comes from a query which is displays "Names" and "calculated Values" associated with names. Now in the same split form i have a combobox and the record source of the combobox comes from a table which stores all the "Names". So now your method works only when " Record source for the Split form and Combobox are same" and if not it gives a runtime error. I hope its more clear than my previous comment , Thanks

Comment: @gizmo: any insights about this issue

Comment: @AdityaIyer not yet